# Glossary acronym without references

Tags: glossaries

Seems silly that I have to ask for such a simple thing but this glossary library is driving me up the wall. What I want to do is to simply display all the acronyms that I have defined after my table of content without having any references to them in my text. So something like this:

```
...
\usepackage[nonumberlist, acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym{Foobar}{Foobar}{foo bar}
...
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \printglossaries
    ...
\end{document}
```

But no matter how I twist and turn the order it just doesn't display correctly. The few times I got it to display it somehow had ghost entries from previous test.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: For example, I don't see `\makeglossaries` in your preamble and `...` as ellipsis in the preamble is just bad ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\makeglossaries` is necessary as well as `\glsaddall` to show all defined acronyms.

Compilation can be done with several methods, but the easiest way is (assuming the source file is called `foo.tex`)

> pdflatex foo
>
> makeglossaries foo

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym{Foobar}{Foobar}{foo bar}
\newacronym{UNESCO}{Unesco}{United Nations Educational, Scientific and Cultural Organization}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\tableofcontents
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It sorta fixed it. Think it's the version of LaTeX that's the problem, using sharelatex.